# Should I use ARC in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

Looking at the release notes of OS 10.7, there's some stuff about using Automatic Reference counting (ARC) to make memory management simple. I'm about to embark on a new Cocoa project soon and wondered whether it would be worth using the model (the way I understand it, you can't mix between using ARC and not using it)?

The dilemma seems to be using something new versus using something that could potentially save lots of debugging time later. But is that the case? Has anyone played around with it and found no real-world benefit?

Comment: Mac OS X (I will probably also make it 10.7+ just so I can take advantage of all the new APIs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without a doubt you should use ARC. ARC injects the retain release calls at the most appropriate times, so you may actually see lower average memory use than you would if you didn't use ARC.

I have used ARC and it is immensely powerful. You stop having random crashes and your app just feels more responsive. As they said at WWDC, there is no reason not to use Automatic Reference Counting.

Also, you **can** use non-ARC files in the same project as ARC files.

Comment: What about backwards compatibility (especially on iOS)?

Comment: Also, it's easier to start using ARC than to convert an app later.

Comment: @mjisrawi: ARC works back through iOS 4.0. In fact, the WWDC app that Apple put out is the first published iOS app to use ARC.

Comment: @jbtule: Of course. And then you haven't wasted time debugging silly memory management issues. I must say, that the ARC migration utility makes it pretty easy though.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should look into it then. :D How big of a task would converting an old project to ARC be?

Comment: @mjisrawi: It's not too bad. The compiler will catch most of the stuff that needs to be converted, but there may be a few things it has trouble with. To do so, go to `Edit` -> `Refactor` -> `Convert to Objective-C ARC...`.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer thanks, I'll have to read up on ARC before taking the leap. Although ARC sounds great I'm gonna take it slowly before refactoring my entire project!

Comment: @mjisrawi: Definitely. Hopefully you have your project under source control, but if not then definitely make sure you create a backup before taking the leap. Good luck!

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Of course! The git integration in XCode 4 is not so bad once you tame it. :D

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer - i'm not disagreeing, but i'm getting mixed messages from the docs and mailing lists - it's not clear to me that everyone should convert everything to ARC straightaway (and i don't mean 'i have decided this', i'm genuinely trying to understand if this is the situation). After 15 years eating-drinking-sleeping Objective-C you don't tend to have 'random crashes' due to memory management errors. Does it really make an app more responsive? You mean you could tell the difference between an ARC app and a no-Arc app just by opening menus, clicking buttons?

Comment: @fakeAccount22: It could all be in my head as most small performance improvements are, but the speakers at WWDC said there were quite a few performance improvements related to ARC, as well as for the new compiler. If you need to support a previous version of iOS before 4.0, then ARC is definitely not for you. Obviously you shouldn't upgrade before you're ready, but for 97% of people, it will increase speed and all but eliminate memory management issues.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Thanks I will definitely go and take a look at the WWDC videos on the topic!

Comment: I think the speed issue is silly to talk about and that it's ridiculous to claim you can observe a speed difference. I think the actual reason for this technology to exist is so folks don't make the mistakes that cause a crash so you end up with stable code from more developers more often. I will end up using ARC, however I think all the misinformation is really irritating. Also, good luck if you've converted to ARC, since you can't even release those apps yet as of the date of this post...

Comment: @Nektarios: The speed improvements are related to releasing resources that would have otherwise been held onto due to missing release statements, not the minuscule speed improvements due to releasing objects at slightly better times. Also, you're right. Apps cannot yet be sent to the store (even though there is at least one already in the store that uses ARC).

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I still don't get how this is a speed improvement in either of those 2 cases, I think the term would be memory efficiency instead of speed though as it's still costing the same amount of processor time unless you hit a penalty of swapping right?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with FreeAsInBeer about using ARC. However, it should also be made clear that **garbage collection (GC) should *not* be used**. It looks like Apple is henceforth going to focus their efforts ARC, while letting GC die a slow death. This is wonderful because ARC is clearly a far superior technology, whereas GC is slow and extremly buggy.

So yes. Use ARC. Stay away from GC.